# Cannot execute method when v-btn clicked with Vuetify

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I can't execute method when clicking v-btn.

### my template

```
<template>
  <v-app>
    <v-main>
      <v-card class="mx-auto" max-width="500" tile>
        <v-text-field
          label="Main input"
          hide-details="auto"
          v-model="newTodo"
        ></v-text-field>
        <v-list disabled>
          <v-subheader>TODOS</v-subheader>
          <v-list-item-group v-model="todos" color="primary">
            <v-list-item v-for="todo in todos" v-bind:key="todo.id">
              <v-list-item-content>
                <v-list-item-title v-text="todo.text"></v-list-item-title>
              </v-list-item-content>
              <v-list-item-action>
                <v-btn color="blue-grey" class="white--text" v-on:click="test">
                  <v-icon dark>mdi-delete</v-icon>
                </v-btn>
              </v-list-item-action>
            </v-list-item>
          </v-list-item-group>
        </v-list>
      </v-card>
    </v-main>
  </v-app>
</template>
```

### my script

```
<script>
export default {
  name: "app",
  data: () => ({
    todos: [],
    newTodo: ""
  }),
  created() {
    this.reload();
  },
  methods: {
    reload() {
      let vm = this;
      const axios = require("axios").create({
        baseURL: "http://localhost:5000",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        responseType: "json"
      });
      axios
        .get("/get_todos")
        .then(function(response) {
          // handle success
          console.log(response);
          vm.todos = response.data;
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
          // handle error
          console.log(error);
        })
        .finally(function() {
          // always executed
        });
    },
    test() {
      console.log("test");
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

### What I've tried

I replaced the "v-on:click" with "@click", "@onclick" and "@click.native" but failed to see "test" on the console.

### Version of plugins

Vue: v2.6.12
Vuetify: v2.3.16

Comment: did you try removing `disabled` from `v-list` ?

Comment: @MichalLevý I've just tried removing disabled and I succeeded to display "test" on my console! Thank you for your comment.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As Michal Levý said, I tried removing disabled from v-list. I succeeded to execute test method.